# Javascript Regex matching multiple repeating blocks

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, match

I need to match a series of repeating `VirtualHost` configs in Javascript, Example:

```
...
# First VHost...
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8082>
    # Any number of configs
    # and set up options for
    # Apache
</VirtualHost>

# Second VHost...
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8082>
    # Any number of configs
    # and set up options for
    # Apache
</VirtualHost>

# Third VHost...
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8082>
    # Any number of configs
    # and set up options for
    # Apache
</VirtualHost>
....
```

My current RegEx Pattern is:

```
/<VirtualHost[*:0-9\s]+>([\S\s]+)<\/VirtualHost>/g
```

I understand that my capturing group is the reason I am getting only one matched set (the whole string as it were), but I don't know how else to capture what is between the VirtualHost blocks.

What I'd like to put output is an array that is: `[<first vhost>, <second vhost>, <third vhost>, ...]` Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use non-greedy regex:

```
/<VirtualHost[*:0-9\s]+>([\S\s]+?)<\/VirtualHost>/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW2xR3/1)

Difference is `[\S\s]+?` vs `[\S\s]+` which is a greedy rexex and matches as much as possible until last `</VirtualHost>` is matched.

Comment: I knew it would be a simple answers. Thanks so much! I will mark as such when SO lets me. 

Non-greedy, learning something new!

Comment: A deeper explanation of why this works would be much appreciated. It feels too lacking to deserve an upvote.

Comment: ok I added an explanation in my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @anubhava That's worked just fine and i learned something new today. I appreciate it.